# *.xaml file can't be loaded properly in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am learning Windows 8 Store App development, in Visual Studio Express 2013, I created a project with template called "Templates->Visual C#->Windows Store", I didn't modify any files of the new created project. And then, I tried to open *.xaml file which created by the Visual Studio, however, I hit below exception, the designer can't load *.xaml file properly.

---

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.    at
>   Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation`1.GetResults()    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.Views.RuntimeResourceManager.GetStorageFileForPath(String
>   indexPath)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.Views.RuntimeResourceManager.ProcessIndexUpdates()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.Views.RuntimeResourceManager.OnNewIndex(String
>   newFileName, String newResourceMapName)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.Views.XamlUIPresenterHostServices.OnResourceIndexUpdated(HostResourceIndexUpdatedEventArgs
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.Views.WindowsUIXamlResourceIndexProvider.OnResourceIndexUpdated(EventArgs
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass13.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__12(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass3`1.b__2()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32
>   lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String
>   methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality,
>   ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath,
>   Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor,
>   RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c_*DisplayClass19.b*_18(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c_*DisplayClass5`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__4(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.b*_0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
>   been returned from a call to a COM component.    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName,
>   String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)

---

Comment: There's [links](http://simplemvvmtoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/1614) out there talking about it. I've seen mention of it being a bug in specifying your own Temp paths etc with VS, but nothing solid. Looks like an interesting one.